# How to call an API in a conditional with React

Tags: reactjs

I would like when I open a modal only launch a service if the modal is open, and re-use the service data for another injection in another component.

Here is the component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FormResolveDispute from '../forms/form-resolve-dispute';
import { useGetAllMovementsByTiersQuery } from '../../services/EventApi';

const ModalResolveEvent = (props: any) => {
const {show, onClose, dispute} = props;
if (show) {
    const {mouvement} = useGetAllMovementsByTiersQuery(
        {
            qp: new URLSearchParams({
                eventId: dispute.id,
            }).toString(),
        },
        {
            selectFromResult: ({data}) => ({
                movement: data?.items || [],
            }),
        }
    );
    return data;
}
return (
    <>
        <Modal show={show} onHide={onClose} centered={true} scrollable={true}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title className="text-title">
                    Test
                </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <FormResolveDispute
                    mvts={mouvement}
                    submitCallback={onClose}
                />
            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    </>
   );
 };

 export default ModalResolveEvent;
```

here I check if `show` is `true` to make the call

```
 if (show) {
   const {movement} = useGetAllMovementsByTiersQuery(
    {
        qp: new URLSearchParams({
            eventId: dispute.id,
        }).toString(),
    },
    {
        selectFromResult: ({data}) => ({
            movement: data?.items || [],
        }),
    }
);
return movement;
```

}

and I would like to inject the movement into the `FormResolveDispute` component.

```
   <FormResolveDispute mvts={movement} submitCallback={onClose} />
```

But I have the following error message

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'movement'.
```

I would like to retrieve the movement generated in the conditonnal to send it back to the `FormResolveEvent`

Could you tell me where the problem is or if there is another way ?

Comment: `TS2304: Cannot find name 'movement'.` It's because movement is inside the scope you must aware. In my opinion you can save the movement to state.

Comment: @edhi.uchiha Thank you for your answer, but how to implement this change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
// create initial state
const [movement, setMovement] = useState([]);

if (show) {
const { movement } = useGetAllMovementsByTiersQuery(
    {
        qp: new URLSearchParams({
            eventId: dispute.id,
        }).toString(),
    },
    {
        selectFromResult: ({data}) => ({
            movement: data?.items || [],
        }),
    }
   );

// set state
setMovement(movement);
}
```

So in this component, movement props is get from state

```
<FormResolveDispute
     mvts={movement}
     submitCallback={onClose}
     />
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but the modification gives me an error message: React Hook "useGetAllMovementsByTiersQuery" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.  I think a react-hook cannot be used in conditional

Comment: Are you use class or functional component ?

Comment: functionnal component

Comment: hm but the problem not because hook used in conditional